# AWS DMS replication issue on database migration between on-premise to AWS RDS service for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

Between On-premise SQL server database and the AWS RDS service for SQL Server, I have set up the AWS DMS sync. Having the following problem right now. Kindly help to troubleshoot this issue. What does the error code mean in the below messages?

> 22-11-10T05:05:02:246333 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]D:  Connection failure error codes are: 00026,00904,10054,4060,01222,55,64,121,1231,233,109,18401,6005,40613  (provider_syntax_manager.c:2114)
>
> 2022-11-10T05:05:02:246381 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]D:  Fatal error codes are: 20028,18470  (provider_syntax_manager.c:2202)
>
> 2022-11-10T05:05:02:246389 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]D:  Table error codes are: 16943,208,11529,1904,1750,8180,207  (provider_syntax_manager.c:2173)
>
> 2022-11-10T05:05:02:246397 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]D:  Data failure error codes are: 7125,8114,6522,511  (provider_syntax_manager.c:2144)

Comment: Try enabling Cloudwatch logs for the task (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/manage-cloudwatch-logs-dms/) and then rerun the task; the logs will provide better information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact error message and DMS task stopping with failure.

The message and the error codes are not so descriptive, but we've found out the user/credentials was different for SQL source of the DMS task.

Once the connection changed to use `sa` the problem was fixed.

HTH.

Comment: What do you mean "changed to use `sa`"? What is `sa`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16#enable-sa-login